# PyScripter Rpyc

Tags: python, pyscripter, rpyc

maybe somebody could give me a couple guidelines how to install Rpyc to PyScripter. I use PyScripter 1.9.9.7 with Python 2.6. I have tried to google it and found some instructions, but still have not succeeded...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the file **rpyc-2.60-py24.zip** from here:

http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/downloads/list

Under your python2.6 install directory go to the following subdirectory

\Lib\site-packages\

check if you already have an rpyc subdirectory,

\Lib\site-packages\Rpyc\

if you do, delete it or delete its contents.

Now unzip the contents of **rpyc-2.60-py24.zip** into

\Lib\site-packages\

maintainng the directory structure within the zip.

Startup pyscripter and within the interpreter window, right click and
select:

**Python Engine->Remote**

Pyscripter should respsond with:

*** Remote Python engine  is active ***

Best of luck!