# pyscripter Rpyc error

Tags: python, pyscripter

pyscripter 2.5.3.0 x64, python 2.7.7 anaconda 2.0.1, windows 7

I was using pyscripter and EPD python happily in 32 bit, no problem. Just changed to 64 bit anaconda version and re-installed everything but now pyscripter cannot import rpyc -- it runs with internal engine (no anaconda), but no such error in pure python.

Thanks very much!

btw, there is a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276323/pyscripter-rpyc) few years ago, but the answer there does not work.

```
*** Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.   
*** Internal Python engine  is active ***
*** Internal Python engine  is active ***
>>> import rpyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpyc\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from rpyc.core import (SocketStream, TunneledSocketStream, PipeStream, Channel,
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rpyc.core.stream import SocketStream, TunneledSocketStream, PipeStream
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 7, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> 



C:\research>python
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import rpyc
>>>
```

Comment: is your second example not using the 64 bit  anaconda?

Comment: It is Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)|

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Year 2017 - same issue